# I changed the name of one of the folders in my home/user folder

Tags: lubuntu, directory

I changed the name of one of my folders in home/user by accident and I don't know what it was called previously. It contains another folder in it called i686-pc-linux-gnu-library. according to file properties, the total size of the file is 0bytes, going in to it shows, i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1 with the final folder, 3.1 being empty.

I used ctrl H to see if there are hidden files and didn't find any. I also used a reference picture i found when i google imaged "ubuntu home/user folder" to kinda work out which one i was missing and they all seemed to be there.

The title of the folder strikes me as something quite important so im afraid if i shut down my laptop, i won't be able to start up or some fatal error like that.

Comment: No, nothing inside your home directory is essential, especially not something which is 0 bytes. You'll be fine.

Comment: What @JonasCz says. Also, this would be a good time to think about making a backup of all the files in your home directory.

Comment: Next time when something like this happens, Press Ctrl+Z  to undo your precious action , the old name will come back (Yes! it really works on 16.04 ;-) )

Comment: Did you have the software "R" downloaded or installed in your home folder? That filename appears to be related to it

Comment: @Nick_Weinberg Yes, I just installed R and Rstudio about 2 days ago.  So will this affect R?